# Can the Setter of a DataTrigger modify a property within the DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datacontext, datatrigger

I have a check box which I plan to implement a 'Select All' feature on.

I figured the easiest implementation was to modify my DataTemplate with a DataTrigger to change the IsChecked property to true/false.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <CheckBox x:Name="Selection" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" />
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SelectAll, Path=IsChecked}" Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="Selection" Property="DataContext.Selected" Value="true" />
            </DataTrigger>
           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SelectAll, Path=IsChecked}" Value="false">
                   <Setter TargetName="Selection" Property="IsChecked" Value="false" />
           </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
  <CheckBox Name="SelectAll />
  <ListView Name="lvSteps"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" />
</Grid>
```

However, this overwrites the binding of the CheckBox which is set to the DataContext property 'Selected' to just the bool values set in the DataTrigger.

Which thinking about it makes perfect sense.

**So my question is, can I change the value of DataContext property within a DataTrigger via Setter?**

So I can keep my CheckBox bound to 'Selected', and change the 'Selected' value within the Setter of the DataTrigger?

Answer (score 1):

you maybe think about it in the wrong way.

`SelectAll` is surly part of your container Element (lets say ListVM) which intern holds your objects (ListItemVM) which contains `Selected` so if you check `SelectAll` you can and should iterate over your Elements and set `Selected` to true and this items use there INotifyPropertyChanged to inform your CheckBox

---

**Edit for Comment**

there is no need to hook up the event of `SelectAll` just bind to it and do your thing in the Set-Part

```
public bool SelectAll
{
   get { return _selectAll;}
   set 
   {
       _selectAll = value;
       RaisPropertyChanged();

       foreach( var item in MyList)
       {
            item.Select = _selectAll;
       }
   }    
}
```

Also why would you like to do this in xaml?

Because you could use interfaces and factor it out in a way that you can us it at many places without code redundancy also you will be able to do it in code from where ever you are able to access the "ListVM"

Comment: This will definitely work by hooking up the Checked/Unchecked events of the SelectAll Check box to a method, and then just iterate over the items setting the Selected value to True or False but it was more about seeing if I could update the DataContext within a Setter just to keep it all in the Xaml.

Comment: Yeah, that would work but I think you're hung up on the 'SelectAll' scenario. It was just a use case of being able to update the DataContext via a Setter which is what I am interested to see if you can do...

Comment: @metoyou as far as i read Dependency Property  should be the key to achiev this see [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126308/wpf-trigger-wont-set-property-if-set-in-element) and [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024053/set-property-of-viewmodel-using-setter-within-some-trigger)