# Can I use a Trigger to write back to the data model within a DataContext?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205473/can-the-setter-of-a-datatrigger-modify-a-property-within-the-datacontext), but that question didn't get an answer that applies to my situation.

I have a listbox with a DataTemplate for display a list of items. I want to be able to have each item in the list be told when the mouse is hovering over it. Here's an example in XAML:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label x:Name="name" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="{Binding MouseOverPropertyInModel}" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And the C#:

```
public partial class DataTriggerSetter : Window
{
    public DataTriggerSetter()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new DataTriggerSetterViewModel();
    }
}

public class DataTriggerSetterViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<SomeModel> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<SomeModel>
    {
        new SomeModel { Name = "Larry", },
        new SomeModel { Name = "Atari", },
    };
}

public class SomeModel
{
    private bool mouseOver;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool MouseOverPropertyInModel { get => mouseOver; set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

And basically have the MouseOverPropertyInModel value get set when the mouse is hovering over it. That example doesn't work because you can't set a binding on the trigger setter property.

I think I can do it by having an invisible checkbox bound to the property, but it seems like a trigger should be able to write back to the data driving the datatemplate and I just don't know the right way. Any suggestions?